# How do I manage many categories in WordPress with WooCommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently, I have a E-commerce site that has about 20k categories and 500 products.

The issue is that when I add 10k - 15k categories and add any products to a few of those categories, the load time when updating a product/post page becomes excessive (over 30 seconds).

Here is an example of the categories I am importing:

500 Manufacturers -> 10 Models each -> 4 Years each

This is oversimplified version of the data, but this would result in 20k categories.

Each product must be able to belong to just a Manufacturer(s) or Manufacturer -> Model(s) or Manufacturer -> Model -> year(s)

Normally I would just create a few tables to represent these relationships; however Wordpress uses a term meta table that creates this:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Example

I would like to know if there is a way to either reference the categories to a different table or make the update button on the back end of WordPress not take over 30 seconds, or if someone has an example of a site that has a large number of categories and does not have this problem

I have tried using caching utilities including wp total cache and a few others - some that use transients, but none of these seem to have any effect.

This issue can be replicated by adding 15k categories and a few products to a Wordpress install with Woocommerce. Then add these products to a few categories and try to update a product.

Comment: Have you tried using tags at least for some of these? Maybe the years?

Comment: This is because you are using categories(500) -> subcategories(x 10) -> subcategories(again x 4), instead of only independent categories (that should be 500 + 10 + 4 = 514… instead of 20k !!! In woocommerce you can set a product with 3 different categories (and no subcategories of categories)… The problem is coming from the import, that is not set correctly, I think (or may be you will need to manipulate the data before importing it).

Comment: Tags do not work and I need 500X10X4, b/c a product could be compatible With Man1 -> mod1 -> 2007 and not Man2 ->mod1 -> 2007 and yes the model names sometimes over lap the years of course over lap many times.  If I did 500 + 10 + 4 that would limit me to only 4 years and lets say for the example 2007 the one 2007 would not be related to  the model or the manufacture.  the category structure is normalized like so http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/second-normal-form-2nf.php